# Campos Dinamicos Laravel - Formulários

Tags: php, laravel

Qual a melhor forma de criar campos dinâmicos na view ?

Suponhamos que eu precise criar diversos produtos no cadastro e mencionar o tipo de produto ou categoria.

Estou usando da seguinte forma:

```
       <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <div class="input-group">
              <input type="produto" class="form-control" value="" id="produto" name="produto[]"
                  placeholder="Nome do Produto">

   <select class="form-control select2" name="categoria[]" style="width: 100%;">
                  <option value="" selected="">Selecione</option>
                  <option value="1">Categoria 1</option>
                  <option value="2">Categoria 2</option>
              </select>
          </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>
```

Estou com problemas para capturar isso no Controller ?
Preciso "casar" os dados de cada produto com a categoria escolhida.

Alguém tem algum exemplo ?

Comment: `Qual a melhor forma de criar campos dinâmicos na View?` **R: a resposta é um framework reativo (`angular`, `vue` ou `reactjs`)**

Comment: Apenas com HTML5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Com Blade do laravel você pode usar o @foreach faz uma listagem no select como segue o exemplo:

```
<select name='categoria'>
   <option value="" disable>Selecione uma categoria</option>
   @foreach($categoria as $categorias)
     <option value="{{$categorias->id}}">{{$categorias->name}}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

No controller estou enviando os dados na variável categoria e listo todos registros de categoria para o select, os valores passados de volta para fazer relacionamento é um ID caso use o nome só trocar o value, e dessa forma listará todas categorias no html usando blade. Se tiver dúvida de como fazer envio dos dados do controller me avise...